# why this java-script function causes page postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to put signature field in a webform page, using this demo http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad and code at https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad.

Why when I click clear button the whole page reload (postback occurred)?
Isn't it a client side call?
How do I prevent it?

aspx html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Signature Pad demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="description" content="Signature Pad - HTML5 canvas based smooth signature drawing using variable width spline interpolation.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signature-pad.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="signature-pad" class="m-signature-pad">
        <div class="m-signature-pad--body">
            <canvas></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
            <div class="description">
                Sign above</div>
            <button class="button clear" data-action="clear">
                Clear</button>
            <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="button save" data-action="save"
                OnClick="Save" />
        </div>
        <script src="js/signature_pad.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app3.js"></script>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfSign" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

app3.js:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
    clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
    saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
    canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad;

// Adjust canvas coordinate space taking into account pixel ratio,
// to make it look crisp on mobile devices.
// This also causes canvas to be cleared.
function resizeCanvas() {
    // When zoomed out to less than 100%, for some very strange reason,
    // some browsers report devicePixelRatio as less than 1
    // and only part of the canvas is cleared then.
    var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    signaturePad.clear();
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert("Please provide signature first.");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hfSign").value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    }
});
```

C# behind code:

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string signature = hfSign.Value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
                btnSave.Text = "Signature Saved!";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `<button>` elements defaults to `<button type="submit">`, so it's actually submitting the form.

To prevent this, you can replace

```
`<button class="button clear" data-action="clear">`
```

with

```
`<button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">`
```

which does nothing by default, or

```
`<button type="reset" class="button clear" data-action="clear">`
```

which by default clears the form.

Comment: I only want to clear the signaturePad not all other fields?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding Then use "button", and clear the field in your click handler.

Comment: what do you mean? did you mean `<button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear" onclick="clear()">`

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of any button in a form is to submit the form. The quick answer is this:

```
clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    signaturePad.clear();
    event.preventDefault(); // stop form submit.
});
```

The more correct answer would be to change the button to this:

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
```

then you could remove the clearButton.addEventListener function and let the default behavior of the reset button clear the form.

Comment: But I only want to clear the signaturePad not all other fields? event.preventDefault() doesnt work.